# Como posso deixar meu app mais leve

Tags: javascript, android, html5, apache-cordova, intel-xdk

Recentemente comecei a criar um aplicativo pelo Intel XDK e por teste percebo que em meu celular o aplicativo roda rapidamente porém em outros ele acaba dando umas travadas.Alguém poderia me dar uma solução ou alguma ideia do que eu possa fazer

Desde já agradeço

Comment: já comparou as configurações do seu celular com os outros? Os serviços que ficam em background podem pesar na hora de rodar um app e isso acaba dando lag.

Comment: Ja tentei comparar sim o meu celular é o Samsung Galaxy J7 e dos demais são Galaxy Note 3 e Galaxy J5 não são celulares ruins são tops

Comment: verifica os serviços em background, quando deixo muita coisa aberta, meu slate6 trava para tudo.